# how to get and convert raw sockets packets to a readable http requests

Tags: python, sockets, http, raw-sockets

I've got here a python code for sniffing raw packets. What I would like is only HTTP packets. How could I convert this to a readable format and get only HTTP packets?

**Python Code**

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 0))
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP,socket.IP_HDRINCL,1)
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL,socket.RCVALL_ON)

while True:
    raw_data = s.recvfrom(65565)
    print str(raw_data).decode('utf-8')

s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL,socket.RCVALL_OFF)
```

**Sample packet**

```
('E\x00\x02X0*@\x00\x80\x06\x00\x00\x7f\x00\x00\x01\x7f\x00\x00\x01\xe6\xc0\xe6\xbfu\x04\x8c\x94\x84*\xec\xe2P\x18\x00\x1d\xe7u\x00\x00\x17\x03\x03\x02+\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
00\x00\x00\x01+\x82x\xdc\xf7\x94\xd6\x0f^\xedC\xab\xb8\xf0^c`\x00\xfb\x8b\xa3\xb7\x90\x8c\x0c\x88\x84\xfb\xc0\xc6S@\x0f\x05uX=o\xef\x17\xbeS\x95b|\x96\x9bLU\xeb\x9e\xa9/K
\xa7\xe8\x83cc\x85\xc8E\xd9\x0b\x86\x9d\xf4\x87\x15K\x14\x1e\n\x13c\xa5\xf9\x1bl\x82\xefQ\xe3_6\xe9O\xc8\xdc@`\xf1\xfb\xdc\xc4g\xc2\xb6\xf02\xcc.\xd9\x92cLV\xa4\xa7za\xa5
pK\xdaNV\x95TKj\xe6W%\x8d\xbf\r\xa0\xb4\xa0H\xfd\xc7\xff\x16\xf7\xa9\x03\xe5#*\x98\xecz\xac\xa7L\xcdEtr\xda\xbd\x81\xb5\x9a\x85\x96n\xb2\x8cqo\xff\xceJ\xc7rn\xe6\xc8\x04\
xd8\x06$K<\x0b\xecO\xad\xf0\x82\xb2\xfa"\x1c\x97\xc9\xcf\xece?h\x06\xc0\x9dE\xec\xcb)P\xb8\xd7\xfa\xe2\xf8\xe0\xa2\xee\xcc5\x19|%\\\xd9\x9a\x93\xa8\xca\x94\xcd\tq\xc3v\xa
1U\xe7\xa7\x00\x99U\x19\x81\x13C\x82; k\xfe;nL\x00}\x08\xdbO\xc5\x91\xd4\xcaR\x8c\xf4\t\xd6Z\x8ewt\x15\xbf\xcd\x15\x97\x7fd\x00\xf1\xa2\x01\xdc.\xb6\xbd\xbd4&\x13\xed\x14
\xa9u\x11\xb3\x11\x8b\xb5\xa3J\r\xafOq\')\xa9!S\x03\x9dd\xc4\x9e\xb8\xc2\xe1\x00\xb4pw\xcbJ\xd9\xfbr\x84\xf9D\x81?\xc7\x85^\xb8dNm\x1b\x97ysVjq-\xb9\xe9\xe6D\xd7\xc9\xd7\
x82\x81\xbf\xc2q6\xf6s\x8e{\xc5\xa6\xd72\xdc<\xeat=y\x0b\xbb]\x94\xfe\xb6\xe1SQ\xafo\x9ef\x9b\xc0%\xd0\xc8\x7f6\xb7\xa1\x04\x02\x86\xab)4@\x1b\xb5\xb3m\xc9[ \x02N,\x9d\xc
4i\x90$\x98\x00\x8bh\x89\xbc\xac\xa0\x86\xeb_\x18dgy\xd6\x15A\x14x\xb3n;\x02\xbe\xb3ir \x84\x9fd\xfd{\x06x\x0c\xab\xdcL*\xcf\x83\xb0r\x1bG6\x9b\xac\xbe\xa4\x84\xabA\xac5\
xb5\xc8\xca\x8f\xc9=\x7f\xafO\xa5\x9a;\xc1\x9dCC\x8a\xb3$:\xcb\x03\xa9\xad\xf8U\x02\xd8-8\xbe\xd4\x12iQaeV\xcbC\x9b\xd5Q\xdee%\xcb\x7f\x00H\xdd\x1a#\x892l\xa4TEg\xda\x1a\
xf8W\xd6\x89\xd0\\\x15\xfbVk\x8b\x9d\x02*\x8f\x13\xa8', ('127.0.0.1', 0))
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: maybe use [scapy](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#quick-demo) to work with raw sockets. Normally you would have to know how is built IP packet and TCP packet to remove them from data - and then you can still get HTTP compressed with `gzip` or `br`

Comment: thanks for your comment but I need this code to run on pydroid and scapy is not working on it for some reason so I decided to go with raw sockets

Comment: What you have shown is not an HTTP packet. If it is HTTPS packet (I'm not going to take the time to decode and parse it to check), then it would be in an encrypted binary format that you cannot decode at all (the whole point of using HTTPS vs HTTP is to avoid 3rd parties sniffing the content).

Comment: If that is not an HTTP packet, please excuse my example because I can't tell which packet is which